# having trouble connecting to mongodb with mongo shell

Tags: mongodb

When I just type in mongo I get the error

```
MongoDB shell version v4.2.8
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
2020-07-08T14:23:38.146+0530 E  QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:341:17
@(connect):2:6
2020-07-08T14:23:38.149+0530 F  -        [main] exception: connect failed
2020-07-08T14:23:38.149+0530 E  -        [main] exiting with code 1
```

How do fix this error?

Comment: Do you have a MongoDB server up and running, on localhost and listening on port 27017?

Comment: Not to my notice is there a way that I can check that.

Comment: How did you install the server? I.e. not the application, I mean the MongoDB service.

Comment: I did install mongo compass but I did quit it

Comment: I reinstalled mongo again but for some reason I can't connect to my cluster. It works but it does not connect.

Comment: it's giving me an authentication error.

Comment: Here is the error: 

connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/mongo?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
2020-07-08T19:55:30.544+0530 E  QUERY    [js] Error: Authentication failed. :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:341:17
@(connect):2:6
2020-07-08T19:55:30.547+0530 F  -        [main] exception: connect failed
2020-07-08T19:55:30.547+0530 E  -        [main] exiting with code 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a older versions of the link in the connect page in the atlas page and used that I used the version 3.4 or earlier; even though my shell is 4.2.8.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you do not yet have MongoDB server installed, or it does not run yet.

Please refer to [the manual](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/installation/).